# Mac Mini 2006 with El Capitan

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini, 2006 (upgraded firmware to 2.1, upgraded CPU to Core 2 Duo, upgraded RAM to 4GB).

With another Mac Mini (2009), I prepared a USB installer of macOS El Capitan patched with MacPostFactor tool.
I used the USB installer to try and install mac OS El Capitan on the Mac Mini (2006) but after a few minutes of the install process it crashes and the Mac Mini restarts with last officially supported macOS 10.6.8.

Does anybody have a working El Capitan on Mac Mini 2006, with instructions on how to get it working?

Comment: It's likely impossible. The Mini, MacBook and Air models not supported on El Cap all seems to be those with the Intel GMA. It may not have the drivers.

Comment: What about this? https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/143340-final-solution-fix-for-gma950-desktop-edition-new-28-dec-08/

Comment: If you've already searched the hobbyist sites, and there's nothing there, then I suspect you're the first person to attempt this. And there's probably a reason for that. ;-)